# How to convert number data to char in data grid column

Tags: c#

I Have code to bring 1 or 0 Data from Table and show it in data grid column 'P' or 'A'. The Problem is 'P' or 'A' is not displaying.

I saved the student attendance 'present' and 'absent' data as '0' And '1'.
I tried to bring this '0' and '1' , and through if else condition (if '1' then display 'P' else if '0' display 'A').

```
if (P == "1" && A == "0")
{
   present = "P";
   dg_attendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value = present;
}
else if ( P== "0" && A == "1")
{
   present = "A";
   dg_attendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value = present;
}
```

I want if 'P' = 1 the Display P else display A

Comment: Are you looking for turnary operator? `dg_attendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value = P == "1" ? "P" : "A";` If `P` is of type `char` (not `string`) `...P == '1' ...`

Comment: if P== 1 then display P and if A ==1 then Display A

Comment: i have values in P and A from database which is '0' or '1'

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you are looking for *turnary operator*, `? :`, e.g.

```
dg_attendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value = P == '1' // assuming P is char
  ? "P"   // if P == '1' return "P" string
  : "A";  // otherwise "A"
```

Comment: sorry i don't understand please clarify it

Comment: @SaadMuneeb it's the same as `if(P == '1')
{
 dg_attendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value = "P";
}
else
{
 dg_attendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value = "A";
}`

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you are assigning the value "P" to a variable and then assigning this variable to the cell value.  If this variable is then changed, then this value will be applied to other instances.

I recommend that you alter your code such that you are applying the value directly.

```
if (P == "1" && A == "0")
{
   // Student is present
   dg_attendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value = "P";
} else if ( P== "0" && A == "1") {
   // Student is absent
   dg_attendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value = "A";
} else {
   // Insufficent data
   dg_attendance.Rows[i].Cells["Present"].Value = "-";
}
```

Comment: @SaadMuneeb and the result was ... ?  You need to clarify what is happening vs what you expect.  If this is not working then you need to review whether the value of `P` is `1` or `0` as everyone in these answers is assuming.

Comment: the value is retrieving 1 and 0 but the conditions i try to apply on 1 and 0 are not working

Comment: @SaadMuneeb The code here will apply the value as indicated.  Check that you do not have another code block that overwrites these values.  I would recommend debugging and stepping through the code to check what is happening.